# Opening all files of a certain filetype in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

For my website, I have one "root" folder with a bunch of subfolders containing many different types of files. Example:

- root folder

  - subfolder
  - subfolder

    - HTML file
    - other files...
  - subfolder

    - HTML file
    - other files...

Many of these subfolders have HTML files in them. I am wondering **if there are any commands I can run to open all of the HTML files in vscode**, or of any filetype for that matter.

I am aware that cmd+control+p allows the selection of a specific file by search, but is there any modification of that for all files of a file type? It is probably possible to write a bash script to do this, but I am not well versed in bash and I am wondering if there are any built-in ways to do this on vscode or plugins I can install to do this.

It also should be noted I am on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Here's on option to find all files that match a given filename specification (`in*.html` in my example) and send that list of files to VS Code via xargs:

```
find . -iname "in*\.html" -print0 | xargs -0 code
```

Comment: For some reason this only gets a few of my HTML files, not all of them

Comment: It always gets the 3 same ones

Comment: The example will get files matching "in*.html", for example index.html. If you want all HTML files, use `-iname "*\.html"`.

Comment: haha yes! @jarmond I was wondering why they all started with "in". The pages were "invite.html", "inspect.html", etc

Comment: Update: jarmond's change worked. Can you please edit your answer to make in only "*\.html" so I can checkmark?